# Ioncube: encryption for non-php file

Tags: ioncube

I would like to ask a question about `ioncube` encryption. I have successfully encrypted a `*.conf` file.

When I run it, it doesn't seems to be running properly.

How can I encrypt a non-php file? Can you give a step by step process?

Comment: Can you further describe what you mean with "not running properly"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All steps taken from the latest [ionCube Encoder User Guide for Version 9](http://www.ioncube.com/sa/USER-GUIDE.pdf) and the [GUI documentation](http://www.ioncube.com/sa/gui_docs/).

---

1. **Encrypt files**

In the command line encoder, you can create encrypted files with the command

```
--encrypt "fileselector"
```

You can chain these together to select multiple files, and use Wilcards as selectors. For example:

```
 ioncube_encoder --encrypt "*.conf" --encrypt "*.xml"
```

In the GUI you can enter these selectors in the 'Source Tab' in your Project settings, under the 'Non-PHP encryption extensions' label:

[image: Source Tab]

---

2. **Loading encrypted files**

Once the files are encrypted, you can read their content by calling the function:

```
mixed ioncube_read_file(string path [,bool &was_encrypted [,string passphrase] ] ] )
```

For example, if you encrypted the file `foo.conf` without passphrase, you can get the content back by calling:

```
$file_content = ioncube_read_file("foo.conf");
```

**Note**: This only works from already encoded files, otherwise the encryption would be useless. Furthermore, encrypted files can only be decrypted by files encoded with the *same* ionCube Encoder, i.e. if you encrypt your files on *Machine 1* and try to decrypt them with files encoded on *Machine 2*, you won't be able to decrypt the file.

Comment: This is my command line to encrypt the file.

/usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_encoder.sh -x86 -53 --encrypt "source.conf" ../Source/source.conf --into /root/Encoded-Source-Code/ToEncodeConf/Encode/

Somethings wrong the way I "encrypt" a non-PHP file?

Comment: @KuhaCoAkawntMo The command appears to be correct. What is the exact error you are facing? Is an encrypted file produced, or do you have problems retrieving the original content in a PHP script?

Comment: Yes, I have problem retrieving the original content. I used this "<?php ioncube_read_file("file_location/source.conf"); ?>" to read the file, but it only returns a value of '7' which means 'An encrypted file cannot be read by an non-encoded PHP script'.

Comment: @KuhaCoAkawntMo As noted in my answer (and as is stated in the errocode's message), encrypted files created with the ionCube Encoder can only be read by an ionCube encoded PHP file. If you create an encoded file and try the same code again, it should work. Does this solve your problem or are there any further errors?